# Abort evaluation in only one window?

Tags: abort

Is there any way to abort evaluation only in *one* window?

I tried both alt .    and quitting the kernel, this stopped evaluation in all windows and actually lost me some time because I only meant to stop in the current window I was in.

Comment: No. A work-around would be to start multiple Mathematicas with each their own window…

Comment: Do you mean different mathematica notebooks with "windows"? Do all notebooks use the same kernel? Assuming they do, you can remove cells from the evaluation queue with `Shift+alt+.`. This means if you start evaluating in notebook1 and then start another evaluation in notebook2, you can abort it with `shift+alt+.` without affecting the evaluation in notebook1.

Comment: yes I mean different notebooks. But does this stop a cell which is already running? I have one cell which just takes forever and all others are nearly instantaneous.

Comment: You can also execute different notebooks in different kernels (you can set the `Evaluator` option in a notebook to point to some other configired kernel, different from the standard one (`"Local"`)). In this case, you can abort evaluation in just one notebook, if it is the only one using that kernel. There is however a licensing limitation to the number or different kernels you can run in parallel - it will depend on the license you have, but you can run at least 2 kernels at the same time.